# Is Marriage with desire considered to be adharma?

Tags: scripture, dharma, tradition, marriage, desire

- Marriage should be made in Love by the couples towards each other.
- Marriages are also conducted with **Desires** like **Beauty,Money,Physical Strength**,etc,....
- Material desires are not considered to be a dharma activity and thier actions are similar to **Business as the actions are for Profit in material** 
  **QUESTION :**
- If marriage made in love is made with desire will the marriage considered like marriage or **Business**.
- If Marriage is done in desire will it be considered **Adharma** as it **Violates the Core of Our Scriptural way for Marriage** ?

Comment: One is married only because of some desires. A desire less person won't marry.

Comment: i think its not relevant question...

Comment: dharma, artha, kama, moksha - are 4 purusharthas. Kama is one of them. Marrying someone helps you attain all of them - do dharmas like yagas and beget good children, earn money, enjoy conjugal pleasures. It is not against shastras to gain profit (artha), or have pleasure (kama). just make sure, it is done within rules - should not cheat in business, should be separate from wife during menses or other spritual days. As long as artha & kama do not conflict with dharma, it is completely fine.

Comment: @ram If both man and woman marrying are in business motivation means ok but for Example : A man is marrying a woman only for doing his duty which was given to him by lord, In the other hand the woman is marrying not for love but only due to his wealth as it would benefit her and her family(Father,mother,etc,...) . By this woman's action it is considered to be a  cheating to her husband. So Is this adharma or Not ?

Comment: @Rohit Its a duty too to marry..because without marriage no children & so no means of paying the Pitru Rina ..I think Shakti here is talking about marriages that are done with ulterior motives..For example many Kings were known to take brides for simply political reasons..He is probably asking whether such marriages are adharma or not..

Comment: @Rickross yes like rickross said  self motives like a business

Comment: Got it then. @Rickross

Comment: See Manu Smriti III. starting with verse 23.